# Identical Text Files (.txt) are not matching

Tags: bash, curl, text, terminal

I'm using Terminal to run a curl request to an API, and am storing the result of that request in a text file.

On a subsequent command, I am comparing a previously stored text file to the new text file where the curl request was stored.

Using a tool text comparison software (https://www.diffchecker.com) to identify any changes between the two files. It's stating that a majority of the text has been removed ----- but the text is exactly the same when I read it:O

Has this happened to anyone else? Not sure how to resolve. I can't post the filed online as they are confidential :(

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're using an _online tool_ to check _confidential files?_ seriously?

Comment: No, we remove the conf, chill ;)

Comment: You don't need an advanced editor to compare files on a Mac, and you *certainly* don't need an online tool. OSX includes everything you need from Terminal.  Try `diff -y file1 file2` for something more visual. If special characters are hiding, use `od -c file | less` to look at your text file's innards.

Comment: Does one file have `\n` line endings and the other have `\r\n` line endings?

Comment: @glennjackman maybe so, how can I check

Comment: If you use `diff` you don't need to care: use the `-b` or `-w` option to ignore changes in whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest tool to compare files is [`cmp`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cmp.1.html)

```
if cmp --quiet file1 file2; then
    echo "files are the same"
else
    echo "files are different"
fi
```

If you're interested in "what changed?" then use `diff` or `comm`

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I'm still getting the same response that I received when using the text editor. I section of the text file that is different is displayed on terminal, but (superficially) they look the same. Is there any way to use diff or comm to check if hidden spaces are in the file?

Answer (score 0):

There a good chance there a difference in the invisible characters. Like space and new lines. You can take an advanced editor like notepad++ and ask him to show invisible chars

Comment: Do you know of an advanced editor I can use that works on Mac? Thanks :)

Comment: I'd vote for `vim`. One of the most advanced editors I know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'compare files' of [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) (Analaysis --> File Compare --> Compare, followed by F6 for each subsequent difference) which will highlight which byte(s) are different in a visual way, and use a hashing tool like [QuickHash](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickhash) you can be certain whether the files are different or not, for certain.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on a Mac and when trying to use QuickHash, I receive an error stating "PowerPC applications are no longer supported." Do you have something that works on Mac?

Comment: Ah, you must be using an older Apple Mac system than Yosemite. Instead, go to the terminal, navigate to where your files are and use the command 'sha1sum'. e.g. YourMac> sha1sum Filename1.txt, followed by sha1sum Filename2.txt If the output is different, the files are. If the output is the same, the files are definately the same.